# Setting the browser zoom-center with javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, zooming

It seems to me that the default zoom-center of modern browsers running on a pc is the top center of the browser's rendering window. 
Is there a way to change this via javascript? 
Just like in mobile devices it's possible to arbitrarily set the zoom-center with pinch-zooming.

Comment: Plain simple: Nope.